# Implementation of OnTimeChangedListener in Android HoneyComb TimePickerDialog for setting timeduration

Tags: android, android-widget

Can anyone help me how to implement OnTimeChangedListener interface in TimePickerDialog of Android 3.0. I am unable to get the reference of timepicker in TimePickerDialog.
Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

**I have answered** for a similar question
[**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356444/get-time-from-timepickers-edit-text/12359945#12359945)

Working with **TimePickerDialog**, this is **my code**:

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int DIALOG_TIME_PICKER = 1;

    private int hours = 10; 
    private int minutes = 30;

    private TextView textViewTimeResult;

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            textViewTimeResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_textview_timeresult);
    }

    public void onTimeResultClick(View view) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_TIME_PICKER);
    }

        @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogId) {

            if (dialogId == DIALOG_TIME_PICKER) {
                    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = 
                            new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerDialogCallBack, hours, minutes, true);
                    return timePickerDialog;
            }
            return super.onCreateDialog(dialogId);
    }

    OnTimeSetListener timePickerDialogCallBack = new OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePickerView, int hoursValue, int minutesValue) {
                    setHours(hoursValue);
                    setMinutes(minutesValue);
                    textViewTimeResult.setText(hoursValue + " : " + minutesValue);
    }
};
```

}

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_textview_timeresult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onTimeResultClick"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="click me to choose time!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!